# Using EqualWidthIconDomain gives error that nobody else in post gets

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

This post is mainly just meant for [rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff), but anybody else is free to help, because I don't know how to contact him other than making a post as I don't have enough reputation to comment.

In your answer on [SwiftUI Multiple Labels Vertically Aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084278/swiftui-multiple-labels-vertically-aligned/68751668#68751668), I tried to implement the code, and even though I changed nothing besides iOS requirements as per XCode warnings, I get the error of `Cannot convert value of type 'VStack<TupleView<(Text, Divider, HStack<TupleView<(VStack<TupleView<(Label<Text, Text>, Label<Text, Image>)>>, VStack<TupleView<(Label<Text, Image>, Label<Text, Image>)>>)>>)>>' to closure result type 'Content'` Is this the result of Xcode 13.4.1, or is it something else? I didn't see anybody have issues with the code.

My code structure is:

```swift
fileprivate struct IconWidthKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat? { nil }

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat?, nextValue: () -> CGFloat?) {
        switch (value, nextValue()) {
        case (nil, let next): value = next
        case (_, nil): break
        case (.some(let current), .some(let next)): value = max(current, next)
        }
    }
}

extension IconWidthKey: EnvironmentKey { }

extension EnvironmentValues {
    fileprivate var iconWidth: CGFloat? {
        get { self[IconWidthKey.self] }
        set { self[IconWidthKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

fileprivate struct IconWidthModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.iconWidth) var width

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: IconWidthKey.self, value: proxy.size.width)
            })
            .frame(width: width)
    }
}

struct EqualIconWidthLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            configuration.icon.modifier(IconWidthModifier())
            configuration.title
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
struct EqualIconWidthDomain<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    @State var iconWidth: CGFloat? = nil

    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .environment(\.iconWidth, iconWidth)
            .onPreferenceChange(IconWidthKey.self) { self.iconWidth = $0 }
            .labelStyle(EqualIconWidthLabelStyle())
}
    




struct WelcomeScreen: View{
...
@ViewBuilder
func playWelcomeScreen() -> some View{
...
EqualIconWidthDomain {
            VStack {
                Text("Le Menu")
                    .font(.caption)
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Label(
                            title: { Text("Strawberry") },
                            icon: { Text("") })
                        Label("Money", systemImage: "banknote")
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Label("People", systemImage: "person.3")
                        Label("Star", systemImage: "star")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just bad copy-pasting, you loose one brace

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
struct EqualIconWidthDomain<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    @State var iconWidth: CGFloat? = nil

    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .environment(\.iconWidth, iconWidth)
            .onPreferenceChange(IconWidthKey.self) { self.iconWidth = $0 }
            .labelStyle(EqualIconWidthLabelStyle())
    } // << here !!
}
```